# How are git arguments parsed?

Tags: git, command, command-line-interface

I am working on my own library to parse argc/argv data. I was thinking about git. How does git arguments work?

Example:

> git commit -m "message"

Here, `commit` is not an option as it doesn't have an hyphen. Is there any place where this type of command line option behavior is explained?

I know my library will be worse than TCLAP or CLAP but I am not allowed to use an external library.

Edit: interesting link -> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70357/command-line-options-style-posix-or-what

Comment: `argparse`, Python's standard library for parsing command-line arguments, calls this type of argument a subcommand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git appears to have different commands, so you can do `git status`, `git add`, etc. So from a user's point of view, `git commit` seems to be an invocation of the command `git` where `commit` is the first argument - when you're doing `argc/argv`, there's absolutely no rule saying that your arguments must begin with dashes or have some other format.

The interesting thing about Git is that it's also extensible. If you create, somewhere in your path, a script called `git-hello` (note single word, with a dash), then you can invoke it by `git hello` on the command line, making it indistinguishable from "real" Git commands.

You might guess from the above that there are actually separate programs called `git-commit`, `git-status` and so on, and that would be a correct guess. It's notable when browsing the `man` pages since you can do something like `man git-commit`. Git does in fact have an execution path where such scripts are located, and you can find it out by running `git --exec-path`. On my system, that's `/usr/lib/git-core` and there's a bunch of separate scripts and symlinks back to Git.

So Git is actually quite unlike most programs in terms of argument handling. You can see how other standard utilities handle their command line arguments in their source. For instance, [this is the source for `cat`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cat.c) in its GNU implementation. If you go their `main`, you'll notice that the argument processing is via a `getopt_long` function, which is, along with `getopt` [described in GNU docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) and is part of `glibc`.

Comment: Okay, but did the "style's command line options" of git have a name ? because the style "-longname" isn't unix/GNU: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html and its not POSIX : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html

It seems like X style : http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/XWindow-User-HOWTO/cli.html ... Did git use its own "getopt" ?

Comment: I am not sure if the Git style has a name. They mix styles. `git add -a` is POSIX, `git commit --amend` is GNU style. Git doesn't use the `-longoption` format as far as I can recall. You can see how Git does things here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git.c . `main` and `handle_alias` are relevant.

Comment: I think I will not support this style ^^ and for the v2 allow user to create it's own format :)